# "invalid recursive type" and "illegal cycle in declaration of"

Tags: go

Shortened example of the two custom types below. "Question" contains a "SavedQuestion" and "SavedQuestion" contains a "Question".

Errors:
1. illegal cycle in declaration of SavedQuestion
2. invalid recursive type Question

```
type Question struct {
    ID                    int           `json:"id"`
    Name                  string        `json:"name"`
    QueryText             string        `json:"query_text"`
    SavedQuestion         SavedQuestion `json:"saved_question"`
}

type SavedQuestion struct {
    ID                       int             `json:"id"`
    Index                    int             `json:"index"`
    Name                     string          `json:"name"`
    Packages                 PackageSpecList `json:"packages"`
    QueryText                string          `json:"query_text"`
    Question                 Question        `json:"question"`
}
```

I'm modeling some types to consume a 3rd party API... The 3rd party API's objects are modeled this way. It seems perfectly normal that a "SavedQuestion" is a separate type that essentially contains a "Question" along with a bunch of other data about it... I can see the loop with a "Question" also containing a "SavedQuestion"... but that's what the API does. As you can see from the json tags I'm just trying to model exactly what the API is sending so I can marshal/unmarshal etc..

How do I make this work? I can make the "Question" in the "SavedQuestion" a pointer to a "Question" and the errors go away... however I don't know if I should or need to do that, or if it will actually work as the code is not yet complete enough to run a test...

New gopher confused...

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot recursively include one struct within another for the simple reason that the size and memory layout of the struct becomes recursive. Size of `Question` is some data + size of (`SavedQuestion`), and size of `SavedQuestion` is size of some data + size of `Question`...

However, if you use pointers, the sizing problem is solved:

```
type Question struct {
    ID                    int           `json:"id"`
    Name                  string        `json:"name"`
    QueryText             string        `json:"query_text"`
    SavedQuestion         *SavedQuestion `json:"saved_question"`
}
```

You need to make sure when to reference `question.SavedQuestion`, it is not nil. This will work just fine for marshaling/unmarshaling. When you unmarshal, if the JSON does not have a `saved_question` element, it'll be nil.